# Link a popup form with a master form

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a continuous form (MasterForm) for data entry based on one table. Some records need additional data, which I want to enter in a separate popup form (which has another table behind). This popup form (SlaveForm) opens by means of a click event in the MasterForm which triggers the DoCmd.OpenForm (vba instruction).

How can I “force” the popup form (SlaveForm) to be “in line” with the last current record of the MasterForm, by VBA code, exactly as I can do in a form/subform format (but here access has explicit tools to do that)?

Edit: See uploaded example
https://gofile.io/?c=VvMfiv   (I am using an external link, since I was not able to find how I can do that in stackOverflow)

In the example, let us supose that we want to add Wagner's Parsifal Opera. After entering the name Parsifal you choose "Have Characters". It will open the SlaveForm (characters), where you want to write "Parsifal" and "Amfortas". However, I am not able to configure the synchronization between the MasterForm and the SlaveForm.

Any suggestion?

Comment: What do you mean by 'in line'? Do you need to apply filter to popup form or pass primary key value to popup? Instead of a popup, consider https://www.fmsinc.com/MicrosoftAccess/Forms/Synchronize/LinkedSubforms.asp

Comment: Last current means what? Open pop-up form with data of current record? If so then use `WhereCondition` parameter of `DoCmd.OpenForm` command.

Comment: Harun yes, open the pop-up with the value of a field of the current record. I've tried what you suggested, but I think I am not maneging the WhereCondition properly.,

Comment: Yes, June7, the problem is exactly to pass the primary key of the mainform (table) to the slaveForm.

Answer (score 1):

After some more digging, I manage to solve the problem. The BeforeInsert event in the slave form is the key. See uploaded file: https://gofile.io/?c=UxRdM8

In the MasterForm there is a text box (which can be set to be invisible) with the primary key (txtIDWork). After the Slave Form has been loaded, and before inserting a new register in the SlaveForm/Table, the BeforeInsert event (of the SlaveForm) assures that the primary key of the MasterForm (of the current register) is set to the foreign key of the SlaveForm:

```
    Private Sub Form_BeforeInsert(Cancel As Integer)
        Me.txtWorkNumber = Forms.frmMaster.txtIDWork
    End Sub
```

where txtWorkNumber is the text box where the foreign key is written (which can be set to be invisible).

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using a subform that is invisible until you need it, then making it visible when you want to enter data, then hide it again once you have filled it in?

Comment: Thanks, Trevor, for your reply. Yes, I did that. But the problem is I cannot have subforms in a continuous form, which is the view state of the MasterForm (as shown in my question).As I can't solve  the original problem, I have already made something like you are suggesting.